# LVM partition says no space even though it's not

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, proxmox

I'm trying to do backups on my Proxmox both to an NFS share. The NFS share is on an Ubuntu (14.04) server with a 2TB HDD separated into 2 x 1TB partitions with LVM.

For some reason (looking with Proxmox) it says the backup folder only have 976MB capacity and 319MB available which causes all my backups to fail due to not having enough space. What could the issue be with the LVM on the ubuntu box?

This following is the contents of `lvdisplay`

```
   --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/is-storage/storage
  LV Name                storage
  VG Name                is-storage
  LV UUID                eTCnzE-DjPt-dky5-tg3Q-BwP4-Dznr-vsr1BU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time san00, 2015-06-27 01:28:08 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.00 GiB
  Current LE             256
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

Comment: LV Size is shown 1.00 GiB... 976MB of capacity is correct. You can grow the logical volume if you have space available. Have a look at the output of `pvs`.

Comment: Oh damn, don't know how I missed that, it's supposed to be 1TB. Thanks for pointing that out!